# Enable div containing a table appear to right of <ul>

Tags: html, css

I'd like some help with finding out why my div table with `id="overalldivcalendartable"` isn't appearing to the right of vertical menu bar i.e. the `div id="div_lhs_menu"`.

I thought the following would help but no luck:

display: inline-block;
float: left;

[Fiddle code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1254/)

[Fiddle full screen demo](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1254/embedded/result/)

HTML:

```
<div class="horizontalmenubar">

    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">MAIN MENU</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">

    <ul id="menu"> <!-- removed id="menu" -->

        <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
            <!-- <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
            </ul>-->
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
            <!-- <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
            </ul>-->
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
            <!-- <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
            </ul>-->
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="div_lhs_menu">

    <ul class="js-css-menu responsive vertical">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <!--<div>

          <ul>
            <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul>
            <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> -->

      </li>

      <li><a href="#">Current</a>
        <!--<div>

          <ul>
            <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul>
            <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> -->
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">Link with Menu</a>
        <!--<div>

          <ul>
            <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul>
            <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> -->
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- JS targets this div -->
<div id="overalldivcalendartable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>Matman</td>
                <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>The</td>
                <td>Tick</td>
                <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>                
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<footer id="footer">
    <section>
        <h3>ABOUT US:</h3>

        <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. <br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. <br></p>             
    </section>

    <section>
        <h3>LIKE, FOLLOW OR WATCH US:</h3>
        <ul class="social">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/facebook.png"/></a></li>               
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter1.png"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/youtube.png"/></a></li>                    
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h3>CONTACT US:</h3>

        <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..<br><br><b>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</b><br><br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..<br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</p>             
    </section>
</footer>

<footer class="footerTwo">
    <p> Copyright &copy; 2015 | qwerty Ltd | All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.horizontalmenubar {
    margin-top: 86px;
    background: #33DD00;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
.horizontalmenubar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
.horizontalmenubar li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width: 200px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
.horizontalmenubar li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.horizontalmenubar li:hover a {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #3366FF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
.horizontalmenubar li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
.horizontalmenubar li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/* Style the <a> tag nested in sub-menus */
.horizontalmenubar li ul li a {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    line-height: 25px;  
}

/* Style the hovering of the <a> tag nested in sub-menus */
.horizontalmenubar li:hover ul li a {
    background: #D6D6D6;
    color: #000000; 
}

/* Style the hovering of the <a> tag nested in sub-menus */
.horizontalmenubar li ul li a:hover {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #3366FF; 
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
.horizontalmenubar ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    .horizontalmenubar ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }

    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    .horizontalmenubar li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }

    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    .horizontalmenubar ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}

/* LHS div */
#div_lhs_menu {
    margin: 10px;
}

/* Main menu */
.js-css-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.js-css-menu, .js-css-menu ul, .js-css-menu li {
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}

.js-css-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li {
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
}

.js-css-menu > li > a {
  color: #555; 
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover > a {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94;
}

/* Dropdown */
.js-css-menu > li div {
  position: absolute; 
  display: none;
  background: #D6D6D6;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul {
  float: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94; 
}

/* Vertical */
.js-css-menu.vertical {
  width: 180px; /* Adjust the width of the vertical menu */
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li {
  display: block; 
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div {
  width: 150px; 
  top: 0;
  left: 181px; /* Adjust the left value according to the width of the vertical menu */
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li a {
  color: #555;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /* LHS div */
    #div_lhs_menu {
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }

    /* Vertical */
    .js-css-menu.vertical {
      width: 100%; /* Adjust the width of the vertical menu */
    }
}

/* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #D6D6D6; 
}

th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}

td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}

#overalldivcalendartable {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px) {

    #overalldivcalendartable {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
    td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
    td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
    td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
    td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
    td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something along these lines:

https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1255/

It is achieved by two changes to your CSS.

```
/* Line 120 */
#div_lhs_menu {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline;
}

/* Line 247 */
#overalldivcalendartable {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks .. your suggestion works but the LHS menu is appearing on the bottom ... see my fiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1257/) .. note .. i changed the table to a calendar as this is my ultimate objective

Answer (score 0):

SOLN:

I was able to set my table div to appear to the right of my vertical menu my nesting both divs in a parent div then setting float left for both my vertical menu div and calendar table div

```
.maindiv {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFCC00;
}

/* LHS div */
.div_lhs_menu {
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    float: left;
}

/*  Generic table styling */
.overalldivcalendartable {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```